# File Upload using URL should allow FTP urls or not?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, ftp

In my project we are uploading files to server, and allowing URLs also. Before using those URLs we validate URL using following validation function:

```
public function checkUrl( $strUrl ) {
    return ( true == preg_match( '/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?/i', $strUrl ) ) ? true : false;
}
```

now in this we have allowed ftp also.

**I just want to know, is it a good idea to allow FTP URLs in file upload?**

Comment: It depends on what you going to do with those files. If it's not possible to access the files directly on server you should be fine. Else you've to care that noting bad can be executed

Answer (score 0):

Personally I avoid this (w. no particular reason). But why not ;)